# Flux react, can an action get a store?

Tags: reactjs, flux

Is it an anti-pattern that an action use something like store.get() ? I'm not sure this is a good idea to do that

Comment: I guess it can but it makes the action coupled to that one store. If you have one store then it might be okay but otherwise no.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard try to post simplified/anonymized examples of what happens in your app. Maybe someone'll suggest another way to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its a bad idea to call `stores` from `actions`. Only place where `stores` should be called is in `views`. For the simple reason that it defies the idea of uni-directional data flow.

It should always be `Views -> Action -> Dispatcher -> Stores -> Views` 
and where as in your case it would be-

```
Views -> Action -> Dispatcher -> Stores -> Views
              ^                   |
              * <-    <-   <-   <-*
```

which is obviously not uni-directional.